# how to insert based on the date

Tags: sql-server, insert, sql-update

I have a table table1 (account, last_contact_date, insert_date), account and last_contact_date are primary keys. The insert_date is set with the time the recored being added by calling getdate(). I also have a temporary table #temp(account, last_contact_date) which I use to update the table1.

Here are sample data:

```
table1
account    last_contact_date    insert_date
1          2012-09-01           2012-09-28
2          2012-09-01           2012-09-28
3          2012-09-01           2012-09-28

#temp 
account    last_contact_date
1          2012-09-27
2          2012-09-27  
3          2012-08-01
```

The result table depends on the inserting date. If the date is 2012-09-28, the result will be

```
table1
account    last_contact_date    insert_date
1          2012-09-27           2012-09-28
2          2012-09-27           2012-09-28
3          2012-09-01           2012-09-28
```

If the date is 2012-09-29, the result will be

```
table1
account    last_contact_date    insert_date
1          2012-09-01           2012-09-28
2          2012-09-01           2012-09-28
3          2012-09-01           2012-09-28
1          2012-09-27           2012-09-29
2          2012-09-27           2012-09-29
```

Basically the rule is 
(1) if the inserting date is the same day, i will pick the lastest last_contact_date, otherwise, 
(2) if the last_contact_date is later than the current last_contact_date, I will insert a new one.

How do I write a query for this insert?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really an insert. It's an update or an insert based upon certain logic.

So, what I recommend is this.

Dump all records into a new temporary table. You will be dumping records from table 1 into the temporary table as is. You will be dumping records from #temp account into the new temporary table as is, but set insert_date column to be the current date.

So, your new temp table would look like this:

```
#holding tank 
account    last_contact_date    insert_date
1          2012-09-01           2012-09-28
2          2012-09-01           2012-09-28
3          2012-09-01           2012-09-28
1          2012-09-27           2012-09-29
2          2012-09-27           2012-09-29
3          2012-08-01           2012-09-29
```

Now, delete all records from table1.

Next, insert new records into table one. We will use a `GROUP` to sort out your records. This is sample code that, in this case, will break your primary key under certain conditions, but you get my point. Massage the grouping logic to suit your needs:

```
Insert into Table1
select
   account,
   max(last_contact_date),
   insert_date
from
  #HoldingTank
group by
  account, insert_date
```

In my opinion, this is the only acceptable way to do this.

I am also quite positive that I would never encounter this situation in practice, because it is a broken design. Some thought needs to be given to this database schema. Store each entity and event in its own table. Based upon my limited knowledge of your situation, I'm thinking of Accounts, Account_Contact_Attempts.

Comment: This is actually probably the fastest way to do this. The alternative is to perform multiple queries, including select, update, and insert.

Comment: Wait, this method will get error if the inserting date is different. The error is Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint.

Comment: You are correct. I read the pkey wrong. However, I'm not here to write your code for you. The concept stands. Delete, select w/ group, and Insert. Adjust your grouping logic to ensure unique 2-col PKeys